# Is the extra top space in a stage included in the size of the scene?

Tags: java, javafx, scene, stage

If I want a scene to be 500 by 500... does that make the stage 550 by 550 or does it make the scene 450 by 450 and the stage 500 by 500? What is the width and length of the extra title bar space above the scene that include the close, restore, and minimize buttons?

Answer (score 1):

No, the extra space on top of a stage is not included in the size of the Scene.

If you want to know the exact size, it is platform dependent. A very simple example to verify is to create a Scene of `500 x 500` and set the Stage at `X=0, Y=0` and check the `mouse co-ordinates` to measure the size.

```
public class MyStageSize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        VBox root = new VBox(label);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setX(0);
        stage.setY(0);
        stage.show();
        scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> label.setText(String.valueOf("X = " + e.getScreenX() + "\nY = " + e.getScreenY())));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```